# Is there a way to rotate google map with single finger?

Tags: google-maps

I know that one can enlarge/shrink the map with single hand by double tapping the screen, holding the second tap and drag up or down. (This actually works for many other app. Not sure if it is built-in behavior of android of just a standard action to handle by developers) Is there a way to rotate the map with single hand?

(well, I got a normal hand, but I find it difficult to use 2 fingers when holding the phone)

Comment: Yes it can be done with single hand..Do you mean with single finger..?

Comment: Yes, and I actually wonder if you can use 2 fingers when you are holding the phone.

Comment: Can u give us the app's names that support this behaviour?

Comment: You mean that trick to enlarge/shrink with single finger? There are many apps supporting this behavior. All browsers (chrome, firefox, the original android browser), ingress (a game by NIA under google), the default image viewer of android and so on. Basically all the apps that offer an enlarge function except those written with flash.